# How can I change CSS style definition to make border on specific div

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this css style definition:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

The css style definition above make border for all bootstrap grid columns in my page.

But I need to set border for bootstrap grid columns in specific div with `id = borderedArea`.

Here is [example](http://jsbin.com/batopijize/1/edit?html,css,output)

How can I change above style definition to make border on specific div with id =`borderedArea`

Comment: `#borderedArea [class*="col-"] { }`? Doesn't that work for you? Seems straight-forward to me (maybe I've misunderstood your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following :

```
#borderedArea [class*="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this CSS3 selector. This will select all elements inside `myDiv` whose classname starts with col-.

```
#myDiv [class^="col-"] {
}
```